# Issue with the object references in Angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I have a simple function below using which am trying create dynamic div containing a d3 chart for each row from the given input "json.res_full_sk"

However, when I use apply in Angularjs, am losing the historic data that is being assigned to dyndata object.

```
<script>
    var app = angular.module('rpPlotExampleApp', ['ui.rpplot']);
    app.controller('rpPlotCtrl', function ($scope) {
        $scope.dyndata={};
        $scope.assign_sk = function (testjsobj) {
            alert('From Angular JS'+ JSON.stringify(testjsobj));
            $scope.dyndata=testjsobj;
        };
    });
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    jsonList = [];
    jsonList.res_full_sk = [
        { "tid": 20, "sk": [{ "name": "Banking", "value": 40, "id": 0 }, { "name": "Housing", "value": 4, "id": 1 }, { "name": "Home", "value": 4, "id": 2 }, { "name": "NET", "value": 4, "id": 3 }] },
        { "tid": 22, "sk": [{ "name": "Movie", "value": 12, "id": 0 }, { "name": "Movie2", "value": 4, "id": 1 }, { "name": "Housing", "value": 4, "id": 2 }, { "name": "Banking", "value": 4, "id": 3 }, { "name": "C", "value": 4, "id": 4 }] },
        { "tid": 24, "sk": [{ "name": "Housing", "value": 4, "id": 0 }, { "name": "Home", "value": 4, "id": 1 }, { "name": "Banking", "value": 4, "id": 2 }] }
    ];
    arr = [];
    function getObjContents(i) {
        arr = $.grep(jsonList.res_full_sk, function (e) {
            return e.tid == i;
        });
        var str = "";
        for (var i = 0; i < arr[0].sk.length; i++) {
            str += ","+ JSON.stringify(arr[0].sk[i]);
        }
        str=str.substring(1);
        str = "[" + str + "]";
        str_obj=JSON.parse(str);
        str_fin = {};
        str_obj.forEach(function (e, i) {
            str_fin['d' + i] = e;
        });
        return str_fin;
    }

    function insertDiv(Num) {
        array = [];
        var ar1 = Num.replace('[', '');
        array = JSON.parse("[" + ar1 + "]");
        var i = 0;
        for (i; i < array.length; i++) {
            js_data={};
            js_data=getObjContents(array[i]);
            testjsobj=js_data;
            var scope = angular.element(document.getElementById("rpPlotCtrl")).scope();
            scope.$watch("dyndata", function (oldval, newval) {
            }, true);
            scope.$apply(function () {
                scope.dyndata = js_data;
            }); 

            var id_num;
            id_num = array[i];
            var rChart = angular.element(document.getElementById("sktemp"));
            rChart.injector().invoke(function ($compile) {
                $('<div obj></div>').insertAfter("#sktemp")
                var obj = $('[obj]'); // get wrapper
                var scope1 = $('[obj]').scope();
                // generate dynamic content
                alert(JSON.stringify(scope1.dyndata));
                obj.html("<div class='skpro' id='skpro" + id_num + "' name='cn'><div class='skprovis' id='skprovis" + id_num + "' >Hello " + id_num + "<div class='half-plot' style='height:95%;width:95%;margin-top:0px;margin-left:5px;'><rp-plot dsn='dyndata' point-radius='1.5' scale='log' labelled='true' class='plot-rp-plot'></rp-plot></div></div></div>");
                // compile!!!
                console.log(obj.contents());
                $compile(obj.contents())(scope1);
                scope1.$apply();
            });
            }
    }
</script>
```

The problem is dyndata is being changed for each value of i in the for loop, and thus the d3 chart is updated with the lastly assigned dyndata object.

As I see the dyndata object is being assigned with different values each time for loop executes, but it is not remaining but changes with the next value of dyndata to all the charts that were created.

How can I get the historic data to persist for dyndata that is already rendered for each for loop execution?

Am new to Angularjs and not very sure how I can make use of Angular.copy() for this scenario.

Problem seems to be with below code -

```
            var scope = angular.element(document.getElementById("rpPlotCtrl")).scope();
            scope.$watch("dyndata", function (oldval, newval) {
            }, true);
            scope.$apply(function () {
                scope.dyndata = js_data;
            });
```

as soon as I assign new js_data value to dyndata, all the existing charts gets updated with new value.

I tried using angular.copy(scope.dyndata)=js_data.. But it didn't work out.

Can you please suggest me?

Comment: You might want to [simplify your problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) first. It appears that you're always selecting the same scope (`getElementById('radialPlotCtrl').scope()`) and then modifying the same property on that scope, so the described result sounds correct.

Comment: Hi @hon2a, Thanks.. I thought it will be incomplete if I dont provide the details and full code for this scenario.. Sorry for a long one!.. I will edit it

Comment: This isn't the angular way to add dynamic content.  Add your data to an array, and use `ng-repeat` to iterate through the array and output an HTML template.  Trying to manually append HTML content should only be necessary in ***extreme*** edge cases, and then usually in a directive.